# Parsing JSON from sdcard - GSON

Tags: android, json, android-layout, android-intent, gson

Hi I created parsing JSON from http server based on [this tutorial](http://androidsmith.com/2011/07/using-gson-to-parse-json-on-android/). But I want parse this JSON file from sdcard. I'm able to print json file location using Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), But I don't know how to change the AsyncTask read the file. can someone help me to do this stuff? (I'm new to android development)
Code looks like this:

```
public class ClientActivity extends Activity {

    TextView capitalTextView;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
        setContentView(R.layout.main1);
        capitalTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.capital_textview);

        this.retrieveCapitals();
    }

    void retrieveCapitals() {

        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this,
                "Please wait...", "Retrieving data...", true, true);

        CapitalsRetrieverAsyncTask task = new CapitalsRetrieverAsyncTask();
        task.execute();
        progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new CancelListener(task));       
    }

    private class CapitalsRetrieverAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        Response response;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String url = "http://sample.com/sample_data.json";
            HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);

            File file = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/example.json");
            System.out.println(file);

            try {
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse getResponse = httpClient.execute(getRequest);
                final int statusCode = getResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) { 
                    Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error " + statusCode + " for URL " + url); 
                    return null;
                }

                HttpEntity getResponseEntity = getResponse.getEntity();
                InputStream httpResponseStream = getResponseEntity.getContent();
                Reader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(httpResponseStream);

                Gson gson = new Gson();
                this.response = gson.fromJson(inputStreamReader, Response.class);
                System.out.println(this.response);
            } 
            catch (IOException e) {
                getRequest.abort();
                Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error for URL " + url, e);
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for (Shop shop : this.response.shops) {

                builder.append(String.format("<br>ID: <b>%s</b><br>Shop: <b>%s</b><br>Description: <b>%s</b><br><br>", shop.getId(), shop.getName(), shop.getDescription()));

            }

            capitalTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(builder.toString()));
            progressDialog.cancel();
        }

    }

    private class CancelListener implements OnCancelListener {

        AsyncTask<?, ?, ?> cancellableTask;

        public CancelListener(AsyncTask<?, ?, ?> task) {
            cancellableTask = task;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            cancellableTask.cancel(true);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't save the JSON file as it is. JSON is meant for transferring values from one place to another.

Instead, depending on the data, you can use Shared Preference or SQLite database to store it.
Check this out:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Then you can easily retrieve it and make modifications to the data.